# javax.xml.bind.JAXBException [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory] in jdk1.5

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am getting error :

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
>    - with linked exception: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]  at
>   javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:195)  at
>   javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:381)     at
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)  at
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)  at
>   com.zhongway.jtjk.cutoverinfo.CutOverInforequest.getCutOVERinfoxml(CutOverInforequest.java:29)
>     at
>   com.zhongway.jtjk.cutoverinfo.CutOverInforequest.main(CutOverInforequest.java:247)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)     at
>   javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:191)  ...
>   5 more

I have added following jars:

> ```
>  javax.xml.bind-2.0.jar   jaxb-2.0-m13-1.jar   jaxb-api-2.0-ea3.jar
> ```

Can someone help me out what wrong with this code.

Comment: You're missing `jaxb-impl-2.0.jar`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add Below dependecy in your pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: See https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl for latest version

Answer (score 0):

File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle

Change gradle jdk